# how to color the exported data table in Excel Sheet , If the code is dynamic?

Tags: javascript

Basically the DATA TABLE is exporting in Excel, But need to change the format of the table, like adding additional cell color or border in the cell. And the Data table is in class and its dynamic

I have already with all the functionalities like ,

```
$js .= '"createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex){
              $(row).addClass(\'redClass\');
              }';
    $js.='customize: function(xlsx){
            var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets["sheet1.xml"];
            $("row c[r*="10"]",sheet).attr("s","25"); 
            },';
```

NO Change in the exported excel sheet

Comment: Is it MySql or Sql-Server? They are not the same. And, if you want to set color to an Excel sheet, why do you tag it as an SQL question? This is one of the best ways to get no help to solve your issue

Comment: Its in JS , So can u help me out? with the code?

Comment: If it is Javascript, don't tag it as C#, php, mysql and sql-server. Tag it as Javascript, so people expert in JS will help you

Comment: It look like you posted server side code that is composing a js object in a string. To have that code executed you have to pass it to a js engine and have code there that will load your string, interpret it as code and then execute it. Please can you provide a more relevant part of your code, just to let us know what is actually going on?

Comment: Yes sure, But i have applied library's for it.